# facebook login button with custom popup

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

i have included a facebook login button like this

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id))
            return;
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js#xfbml=1&amp;appId=592370847463963";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<div class="fb-login-button" data-width="200"></div>
```

but i don't want the default behaviour on click.

is it possible to define my own onclick function for the button?

Answer (score 0):

Well... Please consider that you cannot create custom Facebook Login Page due to security reasons.

Let's assume that this works as you wanted.  It means that you can hijack FB user's name & his password within your page. Nobody will be pleased with this behavior.